# How to create a MS Access macro using C#?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I really do not want to learn Visual Basic and would like to stick with C#. I want to create a MS access macro using C# instead of Visual Basic. Is this possible? How?

Comment: You can, but it is completely pointless.

Horses for courses, old boy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider doing this the other way around. Use Visual Studio to create COM objects in C#, possibly even creating an Add-in for Access. You can do everything you would have done in the Macro, but with a much better development environment, unit tests automated builds, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, through the COM object model: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317114 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee861519.aspx should get you started.